# stackoverflow.mobi

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

By using stackowerflow data dump and spending couple of hours I managed to get it up and running.

Not sure if I’ll get DMCA notice but I have emailed team@stack... yesterday to ask permission. No one replied. I also complied with https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/comment-page-1/

Do you think it is useful? my idea was to make it available on mobile internet.

Another question is after adding non-cluster index (postid,tags) for search, search is still slow. How can i improve performance of search? DB server is sqlserver express 2008

check it at [stackoverflow.mobi](http://stackoverflow.mobi)

Comment: I think you have a typo. Page <title> and banner have a 'w' instead of a 'v'. Search seems fast enough to me.

Comment: i have fixed the typo

Comment: can you edit this, as we did reply to you.. several times!

Comment: Doing a google of `geany autocomplete local variables` gave stackoverflow.mobi a higher rank than stackoverflow.com. Are you dabbling in the dark arts of SEO?

Comment: The page isn't loading...

Comment: SO asked me to return the domain to them, they got big I guess! :) I was supposed to get some goodies in return but nothing came :)

Answer (score 3):

I find it extremely useful, as it is blazing fast and super simple for a quick lookup.

Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Nice work. To answer your question there are many possible ways to speed up a search, starting with full-text index (which SO uses) to faster hamsters, err servers